# Monaco editor - could the intellisense dropdown paginate?

Tags: monaco-editor

We're building a custom language which fetches the intelissense (auto-suggestions) values from the backend. The number of these could be huge, in terms that it's not feasible to load all of them at once (they could even crash the browser).

I'm wondering if the dropdown could use pagination? We're looking for **infinite scroll** (when scrollbar hits the bottom of the dropdown, a new set of results is loaded from the backend and appended to the bottom of the list.

We're **NOT looking for virtualization** (the purpose of virtualization is to keep the data list performance intact, while still preloading all the values at once).

Ideally, the API should receive parameters like:

```
{
    search: 'typed-word-here',
    page: 3,
    page_size: 50
}
```

Thanks!

[image]